# How to change color of buttons made from Scene Builder?

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I have made a few buttons(each represents a city) on SceneBuilder. I need to set their color according to the number of houses in each city. Darker indicating more properties and lighter less (red).

I have assigned each button a fx:id on scene builder and called it in my code but I am not sure how to change it's color by using javafx code.

Can someone help me out, I am very new to Javafx.

`@FXML private Button b1 = new Button();`

First i was trying to test wether or not color would actually change but it does not change

```
@FXML
private void test() {
    for (House s: list) {   
        if(s.getHouse().equals("Manchester") > 10000) {                
            DropShadow s = new DropShadow();
            b1.setEffect(s);        
            b1.setStyle("fx-background-color: #FF0000");
        }
}
```

}

Comment: Post some code please

Comment: Please post your code, or snippets at least

Comment: Done. Can I change the color of buttons from javafx if the button was created in scene builder?

Comment: Change `b1.setStyle("fx-background-color: #FF0000");`  to `b1.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #FF0000");`

Comment: Thank you, it worked for me ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As c0oder pointed out, it was a simple mistake.

Change `b1.setStyle("fx-background-color: #FF0000");` to `b1.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #FF0000");`

This did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the buttons color directly through a property rather than manipulating the style.

Here's an example of changing the text in the button to red:

```
button.setTextFill(Color.RED);
```

This would be changing the background color:

```
button.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.RED, null, null);
```

Comment: `button.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.REED, null, null);` does not compile. Please post tested code.

Comment: It should be Color.RED.
Example: `button.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.RED, null, null);`